# Bing Speech API: speech <-> text with mixed-language inputs

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I want to do speech <-> text with mixed-language inputs.

Initially only Chinese & English, but eventually more language pairs. Vast majority of speech will be English, but small amounts of Chinese will be included. The application is kind of a "conversational verbal dictionary":

- speech-to-text with mixed-language input: "How do you say 猫？"
- text-to-speech with mixed-language input: "The English word for 猫 is Cat." I would want this to be spoken with the voice/accent of a native English speaker.

  - I noticed that the text-to-speech demo at [this URL](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api) can handle sentences like this **IF** you choose the "Chinese-CN", "Chinese-HK", or "Chinese-TW"  accent, but not if you choose any of the "English-*" accents. This doesn't work for me because I need a native English-speaking accent ...

Answer (score 0):

Bing Speech to Text does mixed language support for a small set of vocabulary for Chinese/english. But this is a small set and we do not have plans to expand to other languages this year.

Text To Speech is only available for the voices published.